# How to properly manage underscore mixins via meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, lodash

I want to use lodash and underscore.string, but also need underscore in the project. Underscore [seems to have a method called _.mixin to handle this operation](https://devdocs.io/underscore/index#mixin).

I put the mixins in my `lib/mixins.js` directory so it would be loaded first.

```
_.mixin(lodash);       // loads lodash
_.mixin(s.exports());  // loads underscore.string
```

However, when I open my `meteor shell` and do `console.dir(lodash)` and `console.dir(_)`, I would expect underscore to contain all the same methods as lodash, but it does not. It seems to just be plain underscore.

How are mixins managed with meteor?

Comment: I confirm, the underscore "_" seems to be overridden somewhere and we loose all the mixed in functions. Putting them into the lib folder as suggested Tom does not fix anything. It's probably a bug (or a race condition ?)

Comment: Probably has to do with the shell

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to use lodash but use the mixins very often.

As you did already I placed them at `lib/mixins.js` as well

Mine contains e.g. following code

```
// extended functions
function isDefined(obj) {
  return obj !== void 0;
};

// bring them into scope of underscore
_.mixin({ 'isDefined': isDefined })
```

This is nothing which is relying to meteor but underscore.

I would imagine, that lodash does not return a valib object list.

Should be something like:

`_.mixin({ 'name': function, ... });`

For the strings I guess you should call

`_.mixin(_s.exports());`

This here might be a quite usefull source: http://blog.falafel.com/the-lo-dash-on-underscorejs-and-strings/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of unexpectedly loosing the mixin at some point.
I therefore installed `lodash` instead or underscore

```
meteor add erasaur:meteor-lodash
```

I then put my mixin description file somewhere, (`/lib/moreUnderscore.js`in my case) containing my functions

```
lodash.mixin({ 'something': function(){ ... } })
```

Of course the usage is then `lodash.something` instead of `_.something`